# Схема данных для БД аварийных ситуаций: нужна ваша критика

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Составил для курсового проекта схему базы данных для аварийных ситуаций: можете покритиковать ?
Суть в том, что у каждой внештатной ситуации (EmergencySituation) есть множество причин (Reasons), а у каждой причины есть множество рекомендаций(Recommendation). Причем есть таблица технологических параметров (давление, температура итд ) и она у меня привязана к таблице внештатных ситуаций (EmergencySituation) и рекомендаций (Recommendation). На пример, если у нас давление вышло за границы, мы можешь не только уменьшить давление, но и понизить температуру, к примеру. Не будет ли возникать в моей схеме циклов?

Схема: [link text](http://yadi.sk/d/ySXmcUiqSv6FH)

Comment: в базе данных-то зачем венгерская нотация?

Comment: @Dimitri, опишите бизнес-процесс.

Comment: В программе устанавливаются значения давления, температуры и времени процесса. Через определенные интервал delta происходит проверка текущих значений с верней и нижней границей параметра. Если значение параметра вышло за границы, то пользователю будет предложены причины возникновения нештатной ситуации и рекомендации по их устранению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу так:

- Параметры - таблица с номинальными значениями.
- Ситуации - совокупность значений параметров (один, несколько или все) с отклонениями (двухуровневый справочник с табличной частью).
- Причины - подчиненный ситуациям справочник (можно многие ко многим, чтоб дубли не плодить, если есть в этом смысл).
- Рекомендации - справочник со связью многие ко многим причинам.

Пример.

```
Параметры:
  Темепратура 180
  Давление 1
  Время 0.25

Ситуации:
1.Все ок
  Параметры ситуации:
    Темепратура 170-190
    Давление 0.95-1.05
    Время 0.25-0.28

Причины. 
  1.1. все ок    
    Рекомендация.
      Ждите дальше.

2.Перегрев
  Параметры ситуации:
    Температура 190-220

Причины. 
  2.1. Выделение энергии.
    Рекомендация.
      Снизить температуру.
      Уменьшить давление.
      Прервать процесс.
  2.2. Не работает датчик температуры.
    Рекомендация.
      Проверить датчик. Заменить датчик.
      Прервать процесс.
```

Дальше выборкой по отклонениям номинала параметров получаем ситуации, выводим список возможных причин и рекомендаций.

Comment: Большое спасибо! А как в Access можно изобразить справочник - там же только таблицы ? Или просто таблицу без связей ?

Comment: @Dimitri, ну это да, я так назвал. Справочник - это таблица, которая содержит статические данные, которые не меняются во время работы алгоритма (в отличие от регистра, например).

Comment: Все понял, ещё раз большое спасибо !